# OPC client issue

Tags: java, handshake, opc

I am getting the following error in the OPC client code.
I start my client- close it - start it again to see the following error.
It is clear that something from previous run is causing it. But I am unable to figure out what it is.

When I diff the jstack of my first run and close. I do not see any running thread from opc.

Has anyone seen this issue? Or
Is there some other way I can debug the issue?

```
2016-05-19 16:35:53,564 WARN  [netty-event-loop-0] io.netty.channel.ChannelInitializer - Failed to initialize a channel. Closing: [id: 0xe25cac5b] java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at com.digitalpetri.opcua.stack.client.UaTcpStackClient$1.initChannel(UaTcpStackClient.java:340)
        at com.digitalpetri.opcua.stack.client.UaTcpStackClient$1.initChannel(UaTcpStackClient.java:337)
        at io.netty.channel.ChannelInitializer.channelRegistered(ChannelInitializer.java:69)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRegistered(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:133)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRegistered(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:119)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRegistered(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:733)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.register0(AbstractChannel.java:449)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.access$100(AbstractChannel.java:377)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe$1.run(AbstractChannel.java:423)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:380)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:357)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:116)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 'awaiting-handshake' is already in use
        at io.netty.util.UniqueName.<init>(UniqueName.java:53)
        at io.netty.util.AttributeKey.<init>(AttributeKey.java:47)
        at io.netty.util.AttributeKey.valueOf(AttributeKey.java:39)
        at com.digitalpetri.opcua.stack.client.handlers.UaTcpClientAcknowledgeHandler.<clinit>(UaTcpClientAcknowledgeHandler.java:44)
        ... 13 more
```

Comment: What version of the library is this?

Comment: 1.0.1 @KevinHerron

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you might have some kind of ClassLoader issue - a static final field of UaTcpAcknowledgeHandler is being defined twice somehow.

What exactly happens when you "close" your client?

Comment: When I close the client, it closes fine. I mean there are no lingering threads or any exception.

Comment: Is the JVM shutting down or no? It might be worth upgrading the library to the latest version too. I've seen the client SDK be used in other applications where it shuts down cleanly, so something is wrong with how you're loading and unloading it here.

Comment: I have a driver program.. So the JVM is not shutting down. I have Java 8. Latest OPC libs. You are right that, if I shutdown the JVM and start it again, this problem does not appear, as this is a clean start. But in my case it is not possible, I have to have the JVM running.

Comment: The latest is 1.1.1. You'll have to go into more detail about what your shutdown process is if it doesn't work after upgrading.

Comment: I had upgraded to the latest. I think I need to close some api which will in turn unset the flag for awaiting-handshake. https://github.com/digitalpetri/opc-ua-stack/blob/master/stack-client/src/main/java/com/digitalpetri/opcua/stack/client/handlers/UaTcpClientAcknowledgeHandler.java

Comment: Right now my I disconnect the OpcUaSubscriptionClient